# Meta analysis of multiple IV-regressions

Tags: meta-analysis, instrumental-variables

For simplicity let us consider a single output Y and a single endogenous regressor of interest S. Suppose we have run multiple experiments over different periods in time, where we in each experiment, we have multiple treatment conditions which produce different amounts of variation in S which results in changes in Y only through S (exclusion restriction). You could imagine that we have exogenous covariates X, recorded for each experiment for every unit in the experiment.
Let us assume a constant causal effect p from S -> Y and let us assume that this does not vary with time. 
We can run a TSLS for each experiment to get an estimate for p. My question is what is the best way to combine all these experiments to produce a single "best" causal estimate for p.

Comment: I would consider mvmeta in Stata or R.